# NodeJs Join two tables using sequalize and retrieve the data in Controller

Tags: node.js, express, join

I have two model classes in separate files as below,

```
 module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
        return sequelize.define(
            "course",
            {
                id: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    field: 'ID',
                },
                title: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    field: 'TITLE'
                }
            },
            {
                timestamps: false,
                freezeTableName: true,
                underscored: true
            },
            
        );
    };



  module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
        return sequelize.define(
            "student",
            {
                id: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    field: 'ID',
                },
                courseId: {
                    type: Sequelize.STRING,
                    field: 'COURSE_ID'
                }
            },
            {
                timestamps: false,
                freezeTableName: true,
                underscored: true
            },
            
        );
    };
```

And in the controller I have written like this.

```
const db = require("../config/sequelize.config");
const course = db.course;
const student= db.student;

student.belongsTo(course, {foreignKey: 'courseId', targetKey: 'id'}); 
exports.findStudentData = (req, res) => {

    return student.findOne({ limit: 1 }, 
    {
        include : [{ 
            model: course
    }]}).then(data => {
        
        res.send(data);
    }).
        catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message:
                    err.message || "Some error occurred."
            });
        });

};
```

Here I need to get course data along with student data. When I ran the code it only gives me the student data without course details. I'm not sure If I have added the following statement correct

student.belongsTo(course, {foreignKey: 'courseId', targetKey: 'id'});

Comment: By mentioning `belongsTo` you're just creating the relationship. You need to query the other table or to query a join of them. You can check here: https://sebhastian.com/sequelize-join/

Comment: You should add the reversed relationship (e.g. student belongsTo the course, but course hasMany students). ( https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/ )